# What is the registry key for the context menu of the "Quick access" section in the Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-registry, context-menu

I'd like to remove context menu items I never use from the context menu, which appears when I right-click on the item in the quick access section of the file Explorer. How is the registry key controlling this data called?

Comment: Look at `HKCR\Folder\Shell` key

Comment: Also look at the various methods for managing context menus.   https://www.techspot.com/guides/1670-windows-right-click-menu/

Comment: `HKCR\Folder\Shell` there're no keys I want there :|. I suppose it is somehow connected to the links, because obviously links and not actual folders present in the quick access section.

Comment: What section of Quick Access & what menu items?

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to use shexview.zip

https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/shexview.html